# How do I start to do micro services with Nodejs + Express Framework?

Tags: node.js, express, microservices

I've read microservices and it's about to break the large code(completely different entity) into tiny units so that it can be used anywhere we required

I want to create **microservices** for the website/app that has

1. Authentication(Registration, Login)
2. Home(Dashboard Data with Other User Events, total events count)
3. Event Module(Crud Operations)

I have done the same in the NODE.JS + Express Framework with NoSQL as well as SQL Database but now for the same, I want to do using microservices.

- I have written all the api for login, signup and keep in the 1 server.
- Now I have written all the apis for home(dashboard part) and keep in the 2nd server
- In the last, wrote crud operations for the event module and keep in the 3rd server

Is this way of doing coding in microservices or not, if so then how as I need to use event model for the event count and dashboard data but microservices says it should be independent of one another. So how this can be achieved?

I know this is unlimited but if you guys help me out or giving the suggestion for the same, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Microservice depends in your architecture , try to follow this link https://medium.com/@cramirez92/build-a-nodejs-cinema-microservice-and-deploying-it-with-docker-part-2-e05cc7b126e0

Comment: okay, let me check if I can achieve 1with this.